# TemplateDoesNotExist error in Django Webapp

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I am getting this error when i try to use the default django login page:

TemplateDoesNotExist at /login/
registration/login.html

this is my urls file:

```
    from django.urls import path
    from django.urls import path, include

    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path("", views.home, name="home"),
        path("main-page/", views.main_page, name="main-page"),
        path("kick-page/", views.kick_page, name="kick-page"),
        path('', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")), # add django auth pages for login  
    ]
```

this is my views file:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
    from .forms import * #import all the forms from forms.py


    def home (response):
        form = SignIn()
        return render(response, "main/home.html", {"form": form})

    #need a page to select site/microtik, and add/remove microtiks
    def main_page (response):
        return render(response, "main/main_page.html", {})

    #Need a page that shows the selected mictotik and a form to enter MAC of device to kick
    def kick_page (response):
        return render(response, "main/kick_page.html", {})
```

and this is my directory structure:

```
C:.
└───microsite
    │   db.sqlite3
    │   manage.py
    │
    ├───main
    │   │   admin.py
    │   │   apps.py
    │   │   forms.py
    │   │   models.py
    │   │   tests.py
    │   │   urls.py
    │   │   views.py
    │   │   __init__.py
    │   │
    │   ├───migrations
    │   │   │   __init__.py
    │   │   │
    │   │   └───__pycache__
    │   │           __init__.cpython-311.pyc
    │   │
    │   ├───templates
    │   │   └───main
    │   │       │   base.html
    │   │       │   home.html
    │   │       │   kick_page.html
    │   │       │   main_page.html
    │   │       │
    │   │       └───registration
    │   │               login.html
    │   │
    │   └───__pycache__
    │           admin.cpython-311.pyc
    │           apps.cpython-311.pyc
    │           forms.cpython-311.pyc
    │           models.cpython-311.pyc
    │           urls.cpython-311.pyc
    │           views.cpython-311.pyc
    │           __init__.cpython-311.pyc
    │
    └───microsite
        │   asgi.py
        │   settings.py
        │   urls.py
        │   wsgi.py
        │   __init__.py
        │
        └───__pycache__
                settings.cpython-311.pyc
                urls.cpython-311.pyc
                wsgi.cpython-311.pyc
                __init__.cpython-311.pyc
```

I am following the guide from Tech with Tim to try and add access control to my site so that way the user has to login before getting access to the other views on the site.

I put the error along with my file info into chat GPT and it keeps telling me that the error is caused when the file "login.html" is not stored in a folder called "registration" inside your templates folder.

I have triple checked spelling and verified the file locations but i still cannot get the login page to load. all my other pages are loading fine along with their templates.

If anyone can help me figure out what is going on I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you add your app in the INSTALLED_APPS settings?

Comment: Yes, sorry i did not include my settings.py file because it didnt like my format.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're encountering the `TemplateDoesNotExist` error is due to the placement of your `templates/registration` directory. Please ensure that this directory is located in your project's root directory, specifically at `microsite/templates/registration/login.html`. The correct path for your `login.html` file should be relative to the root of your project to be recognised and accessed by Django.

Comment: so the templates for an app dont go inside the app?

Comment: Typically, app-specific templates are stored within the app's directory. However, Django's authentication views, like the login view, are part of the Django framework and not app-specific. Therefore, Django expects the authentication-related templates, such as 'login.html,' to be in the root directory of your project. This ensures that Django can locate them when needed for authentication views and URLs.